# Flutter application is running successfully on an emulator and a physical Android device but encounters issues on a physical iOS device

Tags: ios, flutter, firebase

Flutter application is running successfully on an emulator and a physical Android device but encounters issues on a physical iOS device
how to solve this issue in my flutter app?

I have used multiple packages in my flutter app which add permission info.plist file:

[image]

Comment: plz add more description what is the actual error msg.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.